# Recaptcha Issue in Internet Explorer and using explicit render

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, modal-dialog, recaptcha

I have two bootstrap modal's and in each of them a form.
In each Form is a placeholder for recaptcha which is fired, if the modal is open.
It works in every browser but not working correctly in Internet Explorer.
If i try to solve the captcha, **placeholder is still there** and **Button is still disabled**. (WTF?!)

http://jsbin.com/sukulujodi/1/edit?html,js,output

Maybe ist a Problem with try and catch, but i think is a Problem because of the iFrame or simple because of IE.
Is there a solution for this explicit render Problem in IE?

Comment: Thank you very much @Happy!
I'm not a expert in IE debugging but it seems there is no access for a script:
`https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.de.1xhhQJ-eiPg.O/m=gapi_iframes,gapi_iframes_style_common/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCMmASyiNvSNbn83FW9tfotfkVsbEA/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_0`
But i dont know why. I ask tomorrow in Google Groups Forum. Gn8

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I've created this JSFiddle to demonstrate it even more clearly: http://fiddle.jshell.net/emilhem/Lgovn28f/6/

Comment: It's the other way around. This is the first question and the one you linked to is the duplicate (when looking at the date). The issue is that question provides a working answer while this one doesn't.